# Setting edge thickness in igraph's tkplot using a weighted network

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, weighted

Fairly straightforward, I'm working with a lot of network data represented as adjacency matrices. I've been using R's igraph package with some success and I'm just trying to figure out a way to set the width of the edges in the tkplot output to automatically scale to the width of that edge in the adjacency matrix. So the edges with more weights are thicker, etc.

I'm not very familiar with other representational forms of edges (such as edge lists) so some kind of idea grounded in adjacency matrices would be superb.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think this will help you.
[Change edge thickness in igraph plot R according to Edge Attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301119/change-edge-thickness-in-igraph-plot-r-according-to-edge-attributes)

Comment: If you're working with a lot of network data, an adjacency matrix will take up much more space/memory (and be harder to work with) than an edge list. If you already have an adjacency matrix, it should be simple to translate it into an edge list with weights and use the weights as the parameter for edge width.