# Change edge thickness according to a column of a dataframe containing relations between actors

Tags: r, plot, igraph

This code plots a graph from dataframes of actors and relations.

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        friendship=c(4,15,5,2,11,1))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)

plot(g)
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like to change the thickness (not the length) of the arcs based on the value of `relations$friendship`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301119/change-edge-thickness-in-igraph-plot-r-according-to-edge-attributes , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269705/plot-edges-based-on-weight-using-r-igraph, e.g. `plot(g, edge.width=E(g)$friendship)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
plot(g,edge.width = E(g)$friendship, edge.arrow.size = E(g)$friendship)
```

[image]

---

Note that, the first value of `E(g)$friendship` is assigned to `edge.arrow.size`, instead of a vector. Maybe the improved feature will be added to future `igraph` version.

> **arrow.size** The size of the arrows. Currently this is a constant, so it
> is the same for every edge. If a vector is submitted then only the
> first element is used, ie. if this is taken from an edge attribute
> then only the attribute of the first edge is used for all arrows. This
> will likely change in the future.
>
> The default value is 1.
>
> **arrow.width** The width of the arrows. Currently this is a constant, so
> it is the same for every edge. If a vector is submitted then only the
> first element is used, ie. if this is taken from an edge attribute
> then only the attribute of the first edge is used for all arrows. This
> will likely change in the future.
>
> This argument is currently only used by plot.igraph.
>
> The default value is 1, which gives the same width as before this
> option appeared in igraph.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved very simply.
First your code:

```
library(igraph)

actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        friendship=c(4,15,5,2,11,1))
g <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
```

Now let's create a graph with a thickness of 2, line color black and line type 2.

```
plot(g, edge.width = 2, edge.color = "black", edge.lty = 2)
```

[image]

Of course, you can change it as you like

```
plot(g, edge.width = 5, edge.color = "black", edge.lty = 1)
```

[image]

Hope that's what you meant.

**Small update**

Finally, you may want to find the coordinates of the elements. You can do it this way:

```
coords = layout_nicely(g)
coords[5,]=c(20, 20)
coords
```

output

```
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 15.21285 18.97650
[2,] 15.18511 20.08411
[3,] 14.21575 19.70269
[4,] 16.17453 19.75255
[5,] 20.00000 20.00000
```

Plot

```
plot(g, layout=coords, edge.width = 5, edge.color = "black", edge.lty = 1)
```

[image]

You can also set other cutout attributes

```
plot(g, vertex.size = 20, vertex.color = "red", vertex.shape = "square", 
     edge.width = 3, edge.color = "black", edge.lty = 3, 
     edge.label = relations$friendship, edge.curved = TRUE)
```

[image]

Also note that any of these parameters can also come from a vector.
So there is no obstacle for the thickness to come from the variable `friendship`, for example.

```
plot(g, vertex.size = 20, vertex.color = "red", 
     vertex.shape = c("square","circle","square","circle","rectangle"), 
     edge.width = relations$friendship, edge.color = "black", edge.lty = c(1,2,3,1,2,3), 
     edge.label = 10:20, edge.curved = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how your answer resolves the question of how to *"change the thickness of the arcs"*. All of the line thicknesses here are identical, regardless of `$friendship`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Dear @r2evans, you are absolutely right! I just assigned `relations$friendship` to `edge.label` instead of `edge.width` out of momentum. I hope this minor oversight will be forgiven.

Comment: Dear @r2evans, you are very nice. Thanks for **all** the upvotes I have received recently from you :-).

Comment: Regarding the above question, when I read it, it seemed almost impossible that @Mark could only ask about such a minor matter as setting the thickness of the arrows and even fund a reward for the answer. You probably know better from me that sometimes people on SO people ask about something more than what can be read from the content of their question. In any case, it has happened to me several times that when writing an answer that accurately corresponded to the question asked, I did not receive approval because someone answered a bit more broadly.

Comment: Answers are not always accepted based on objective metrics, sometimes they are accepted because of timing, or that a better and more-generic answer looks much scarier. If the acceptance were controlled by those who know better about the material, SO would be a very different place. I agree that it can be frustrating, but ... I can't claim not getting my "money's worth" out of this based on the $$$ cost of entry :-)

Comment: I have already learned this learning :-)